# Sub-menu exceeds the available height of a page, possible solutions?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I created a simple vertical navigation bar using only HTML and CSS and added sub-menus. Now the problem is, the sub-menus of the lower nav-menus have a lot of links which causes the sub-menu to exceed the height of the page. The screenshot explains better -

[image]

As you can see, the sub-menu exceeds the height of the webpage, and the footer (dark gray strip with © sign) ends up floating in mid air. The biggest problem is that the `"outerwear"` has even longer sub-menu and I ended up scrolling down to view the rest of the hidden links.

Is there a solution for this using **only** HTML and CSS? Possible to align the bottom margin (not in a technical sense) of the sub-menu with the bottom margin of the main menu?

**EDIT**: Here's the code - http://jsfiddle.net/nWxpj/2/

Comment: I don't think you are addressing the bigger problem—having a drilldown menu that large is not user friendly at all. Look at using a mega dropdown menu or split the sub menus into subnavs on landing pages

Comment: What are we supposed to do without seeing the page or any code?

Comment: @ckaufman - yes, I know. But that's the client's wish. I told him about it, and even gave him a better solution for that: to add a one more tab on the horizontal navigation (which is on the top) and, like you said, add a mega dropdown menu. He wasn't interested and insisted on having a vertical one.

Comment: @Sparky672 - I think the HTML and CSS is pretty straight-forward, but I'll add a fiddle.

Comment: Please include the code in your question as well.  Otherwise, these questions are useless to future readers when the links go dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sub menu list items vary, so i think its not possible to achieve without defining separate class, so you have to define separate classes for bottom menus and set the top-margin according to,

here what i did, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nWxpj/4/)